# Excel VBA: Find and Delete Multiple Values from Strings in One Column

Tags: excel, onlinebanking, vba

Background: I need to clean up a CSV file of my bank statement for use in an online financial reporting tool.

The transactions are all in the following formats (columns seperated by commas):

```
0901XX 892XXXXX, 24/12/2010, CARD PAYMENT TO MICKEY MOUSE29.90 GBP ON 22-12-2010, -29.9
```

The problem I have is that the information in the thrid column is all unique because of the inclusion of the transaction amount and date - "CARD PAYMENT TO MICKEY MOUSE**29.90 GBP ON 22-12-2010**". Consequently, I'm forced to categorise all 200+ transactions individually, which is not condusive with my mental wellbeing.

The best solution I can think of is to remove all numbers from this column and find and replace all of the redundant terms ("GBP ON", ".", "-") with a null value, but I'm not sure how to go about putting that together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its me, or you are not specifying what you want to KEEP from the third column.

Comment: is the data originally in an excel wrokbook that you are then saving as .csv to upload to the online tool?

Comment: Perhaps you can use analysis heading. For example, in E1 you have "CARD PAYMENT", in C4 you have "CARD PAYMENT TO MICKEY MOUSE", in D4 you have the monetary vale and in E4 you have a formula that checks for the header string in the text of C4 `=IF(ISERROR(FIND(E$1,$C4,1)),"",$D4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may help you. I am making the following assumptions:

1. You are getting your online banking details in a .csv format initially
2. Your third column is always of the form `TextDescription+Amount+Currency+Date`
3. In the .csv file, the third column is column C in the workbook

Follow these steps:

1. Open .csv file
2. Open VBE editor by pressing `ALT + F11`
3. Select **Insert > Module** from toolbar
4. In module paste the following code, place cursor anywhere in code, and then hit `F5'

   ```
   Sub CleanTransaction()
   Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
   Dim lastRow As Long, iChar As Long
   lastRow = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
   Set rng = Range("C1:C" & lastRow)


   For Each cl In rng
      For iChar = 1 To Len(cl)
          If IsNumeric((VBA.Mid$(cl, iChar, 1))) Then
              cl = VBA.Trim$(VBA.Left$(cl, iChar - 1))
          End If
      Next iChar
   Next cl    
   End Sub
   ```

This should do the following for each item in column C:

```
CARD PAYMENT TO MICKEY MOUSE29.90 GBP ON 22-12-2010
```

...becomes...

```
CARD PAYMENT TO MICKEY MOUSE
```

Note that the code works by looking for the first occurence of a number in the description and stripping out everything after that. This assumes that first occurence of a number **always** denotes the price. If the payment recipient had a number in the name then the code would fail e.g. CARD PAYMENT TO PHONES4U

Comment: Remnant that works great! Minus the odd ATM withdrawal listed as "CASH WITHDRAWAL AT LLOYDS TSB BANK PLC ATM 123 FULHAM BROADWAY LONDON" it's absolutely perfect. BTW, the instructions you wrote were very clear and assumed no prior knowledge - a true expert. Kudos.

Comment: Instead of stripping after the first number, you might want to find the first decimal point, then backup 6 characters and start looking for the first number from there.  Might be a better chance of having a number than a period in the description.  Then you should Exit For after you've found the number.